# Why does DNSstuff fail but SPF softfail?

Tags: spf

Why does this online tool fail the SPF check

http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#spf|type=ipv4&&value=155.133.82.39&&email=fake@gmail.com

But an installed Perl SPF check softfails the SPF check?

> May  9 00:48:49 ip-172-31-15-65 postfix/policy-spf[5905]: Policy action=PREPEND Received-SPF: softfail (gmail.com ... _spf.google.com: Sender is not authorized by default to use 'fake@gmail.com' in 'mfrom' identity, however domain is not currently prepared for false failures (mechanism '~all' matched)) receiver=ip-172-31-15-99.us-west-2.compute.internal; identity=mailfrom; envelope-from="fake@gmail.com"; helo=gmail.com; client-ip=155.133.82.39

This is the SPF record for gmail: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3agmail.com&run=toolpage#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the DNSStuff tool doesn't distinguish between soft (`~all`) and hard (`-all`) fails; try http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#spf|type=ipv4&&value=155.133.82.39&&email=fake@teaparty.net , bearing in mind that `teaparty.net`'s SPF record terminates `-all`, and note that it still just says "X Fail" by way of result.

Your installed perl is making that distinction; good for it.

To look a little harder, I tried DNSStuff with a non-existent domain, and also got "X Fail"; I suspect it would be the same if I tried with a domain that had a syntactically-invalid SPF record.  What DNSStuff's toolbox seems to be evaluating is "*Is there a good reason to **accept** this email?*".  The problem is, as I have tried to explain to many people who prefer `~all` to `-all`, is that **nobody uses SPF to determine what to accept**.  What we all care about is "*Is there a good reason to **discard** this email?*", because unless you want to lose email randomly, you need to discard out of hand *only* email that the (purported) sender has told you can be discarded, and accept everything else for further processing.

In my opinion, DNSStuff's toolbox is not a good one, and you should ignore its results.